# Is EclipseLink MOXy suitable for ridiculously huge XML files?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

I've spent some enjoyable time with EclipseLink MOXy, figuring out the best way to parse XML into POJOs within Spring. I've now been given some XML to parse, and the files go up to a quite unbelievably 750MiB in size.

Does EclipseLink MOXy use streaming tech underneath, or will it try to hold the whole document in memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/#moxy) lead and a member of the [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

Whenever possible [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/#moxy) leverages a StAX `XMLStreamReader` to process the XML input.  This means the document is never held in memory.

Comment: Blaise - I've been using external metadata configuration. Any suggestions on how I can go about 'iterating' over many records in a single file and triggering some sort of event when each has been parsed? Otherwise, whilst the XML wwon't be held in memory, the POJO representations will all be on the heap at once.

Comment: @Deejay - I think you are looking for the approach suggested by Ian Roberts: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13397375/383861

Answer (score 3):

I can't comment on MOXy vs. any other JAXB implementation, but depending on the structure of your XML files and the kind of data they contain you may want to consider something other than the obvious approach of unmarshalling your whole XML file into objects up front and then manipulating them.  For example, if the very large file consists of many small segments

```
<root>
  <record>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Ian</name>
  </record>
  <record>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>Deejay</name>
  </record>
  <!-- 100,000 more <record> elements -->
</root>
```

you may be able to process each segment individually using something like

```
XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);
JAXBContext ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.example");
Unmarshaller um = ctx.createUnmarshaller();
xsr.nextTag(); // move to the <root> tag
xsr.nextTag(); // move to the first <record>

// read one <record> at a time
JAXBElement<Record> rec = um.unmarshal(xsr, Record.class);
// leaves the xsr pointing to the token after the </record> tag
// so you can do something with this Record, then discard it and
// parse the next...
```